# change multiple textbox value using ajax on textbox value change

Tags: php, ajax

I have multiple textboxes on my PHP page.like basic salary,transport,medical allowance ,fund,
when I enter the basic salary then it should change the value of transport textbox using ajax by fetching from database and when transport textbox value is changed using  ajax then another textbox fund value should also be change using the same ajax function.

How can I do that?

Until now I am able to change the value of second text box using ajax but when the second textbox is populated using ajax then third textbox value does not get changed.

Comment: Bind an onChange event to trnasport text box or call another ajax function to find the fund when transport textbox value changes.Or  you can trigger the second ajax function ajax onSuccess of basic salary change.

Comment: Please provide code. We can't help you very well if we can't see some code.

Comment: Provide sample code for better solution or make a sample jsfiddle

Answer (score 0):

If something works in one part of your code and not in another, you should debug your code step-by-step

- make sure there's an onchange event
- check the parameters (values) sent to the AJAX request
- dump the data that comes back
- assuming you have an onsuccess listener check if it's trying to change the value of a correct field. It may be a question of simple typo when you use getElementById()
- check your error console